# No alloc c xml parser

Tags: xml, parsing, saxparser

Is there a c xml parser that does not allocate any memory and just returns ptr and size in original buffer (aka token parser)?

I'm trying out libxml2 and I was trying but it does allocate every string. To me when I want to deserialize values I don't want to dup them.

Comment: What if the strings contain entities?

Comment: Does not change anything, I'm looking for xml token parser.

Comment: I'm sure you are. SO, for better or worse, doesn't allow questions of the form "Please recommend a software package". See [help/dont-ask]. My question to you was a bit too abbreviated, I'm afraid. I should have asked, "Suppose the string contains an entity. How do you expect the entity to be expanded without a memory allocation?" But you don't have to answer. It was mostly rhetorical.

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong help shortcut. The one I meant to use was [help/on-topic]. (See #3 in the list of categories of questions which are not on-topic.)